# Refactoring a class method to be under an abstract base class and splitting the logic without changing the base class method signature?

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm currently working on redesigning a class to be under an abstract base class. The current class has a method `func` that does some logic for two things, say `A` and `B`.

(note that all the code below is very simplified. There's a lot more functionality than what is shown)

```
class current_class:
  def func(self):
    # does stuff for A 
    # does stuff for B
```

During logic `A`, it loads a large dataset into a dictionary, say, `dataset` and later `dataset.keys()` is used for logic `B`, but other than that, `A` and `B` are independent of each other.

I will create an alternate class, say, `another_class` that is similar to `current_class`, but this class doesn't need `B` and only needs `A`. So something like

```
class another_class:
  def func(self):
    # does stuff for A
```

And then both will be under an abstract base class `base`. Since both inherited classes involves `A`, I plan on just creating a method in base class that does `A`, say, `func_A`. But I'm having trouble with figuring out the best way to approach this so that the function signatures conform and without having to reload `dataset` for `B`.

If `another_class` also needed the logic for `B`, I think we can just return `dataset.keys()` from `func_A` and use it in `func_B`, but `another_class` doesn't.

So I don't know if there's a good way to conform this without having different signatures for the methods.

So in code, I have the following two ideas:

1)

```
class base:
  @abstractmethod
  def func(self):
    pass
  def func_A(self):
    # does stuff for A and gets the dataset
    return dataset.keys()

class current_class:
  def func_B(self, keys):
    # does stuff for B
  def func(self):
    keys = self.func_A
    self.func_B(keys)

class current_class:
  def func(self):
    _ = self.func_A() # the return is unused...
```

2. 

```
class base:
  @abstractmethod
  def func(self):
    pass


class current_class:
  def func_A(self):
    # does stuff for A and gets the dataset
    return dataset.keys()
  def func_B(self, keys):
    # does stuff for B
  def func(self):
    keys = self.func_A()
    self.func_B(keys)

class current_class:
  def func_A(self):
    # does same stuff as func_A for current_class, and doesn't return anything
  def func(self):
    self.func_A()
```

I don't like the first design because `func_A` only needs to return something for one of the subclasses and not for all of them. I also don't like the second design because we have to separately implement `func_A` in each inherited class even though they're identical methods, except one needs to return something and the other doesn't.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What does the abstract base class define the two children need to override? It seems like you could simply write a regular function `do_A` that could be called from both `func` methods.

Comment: @chepner I just edited the OP to include my thoughts. Hopefully that clears the confusion

Comment: There's not enough justification here for there to be *any* base class, let alone the need for it to be abstract. Just because `current_class_1` and `current_class_2` (I assume these are to be distinguished from each other) both need to call a common function doesn't mean that function needs to be inherited from a common base class. `func_a` could just as well be a regular function.

Comment: @chepner So this is just a very simplified example. The `base` class is needed because there's a lot of other shared functionality that isn't shown here.

Comment: Just because `func_A` returns something doesn't mean you have to use it. You call functions that return `None` every day and ignore *their* return values.

Comment: @chepner yes, but I feel like a good design that introduce things in a base class that doesn't apply to all inherited classes

Comment: How often do you check the return value of a file's `write` method for the number of  bytes it wrote? Just because a method is *useful* to a subclass doesn't mean you have to make full use of it in *every* subclass.

Comment: Don't you need to do `self.func_B(keys)`?

Comment: @Barmar yes. I just made the change

Answer (score 1):

It's not a big deal to ignore the return value of a function that is primarily called for its side effects. Just define `func_A` once in the base class and let both child classes use it as appropriate to their needs.

```
class Base:
    @abstractmethod
    def func(self):
        pass

    def func_A(self):
        # does stuff for A and gets the dataset
        return dataset.keys()


class Child1:
    def func_B(self, keys):
        # does stuff for B
    def func(self):
        keys = self.func_A
        self.func_B(keys)


class Child2:
    def func(self):
        self.func_A()
```

If there is *more* in `func_A` that isn't necessary for `Child2`, then it should of course be split up to avoid doing unnecessary work in `Child2.func`. But simply returning a value is not in anyway time- or space-intensive, and should not be a concern.

Comment: I suppose one issue with this design is the `dataset.keys()` call it self, which might be expensive? I'm actually not sure if it is or not without profiling

Comment: You said `dataset` was a `dict`. The construction of the `dict` may be time-consuming, but its `keys` method returns an iterable in O(1). If you don't iterate over it, it doesn't consume any additional resources.